# ASPX about list<Object> and sorting

Tags: c#, list

I am a php programmer. Unlucky that I have to face some Aspx problem.

I have two dataSource list Objects:

```
List < Event > eventSource=eventSource.ToList();
List < News > newsSource=newData.ToList();
```

Although event and News had the same fields(id, title, description, last_updated), they are stored in the different tables (news and event), and there is no relationship between two tables. Both of them had last_updated field which contain a datetime. I need to join them into one table and sort them by last_updated desc.

Then I write something funny with my java(?) knowledge:

```
List < Object > resultSource=new List < Object >();
foreach (Event eventInfo in eventSource){
   resultSource.Add(eventInfo);
}
```

I have loop the newsSource and add them in the resultSource. Then I try to use this to sort by datetime:

```
resultSource=resultSource.OrderBy(???).ToList();
```

But I don't know what parameter should be filled in that ??? area, and I found that I cannot get the "resultInfo.title" in the foreach loop, because I don't have "title" field in the Object class.

Do I have anyway to solve this in simple way?

Comment: If you can change the `Event` and `News` class (for example, if they are declared as `partial`), you can try creating a common `interface` for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lambda expression.
Something like:

```
resultSource=resultSource.OrderBy(res => res.Name).ToList();
```

But replace `Name` with whatever property that you want to sort on.

Comment: I don't think this will work for them, because `Event` and `News` are not related types, which is the reason why the list they're trying to sort is of type `object` (and `object` does not have a "`Name`" property).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have solve the problems. First I use resultSource < Event > to replace the resultSource < Object >. Then I loop up the news source, create a new Event object in the looping, add them back from news to event "fields by fields" to fill the new Event object, then add it in the resultSource. Last, I use Ofer Zelig's OrderBy function to finish my job.